# Subfloor damage under exterior wall

Tags: subfloor, water-damage, rot

I am upgrading our kitchen and have found some damage to the subfloor from previous water leaks. These leaks were fixed long ago and there is no moisture in the subfloor or surrounding wood. We ripped out the subfloor up to the exterior wall (pictured) (there is also a window here) but it looks like there might be some damage past this point. I am wondering if I need to remove the subfloor underneath the window or if this will suffice. I have sprayed with mold treatment and have checked the 2x4 in the window frame which does not seem soft (with the screwdriver test). Am I being too meticulous and this looks fine? Please let me know what you think. Thanks[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is an opinion question, which is off-topic here. Mine is that the cause of the damage has been mitigated, there's no real _problem_, so don't worry about it. Some will call this lazy. I call it reasonable.

Comment: Do yank all that nasty insulation and replace it, though. That should've been step 1 after opening things up.

Comment: Given that it will be very difficult (at best) to remove that plywood from under the wall without lifting the entire wall, I think it's entirely reasonable to leave it. If what you see isn't damaged significantly and it's dried out, there's no reason to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say from a photo but it appears that there is damage to the piece marked below.  It's also quite possible that there is more damage on the other side of this wall that you cannot see now.

I'd tear the whole thing out and fix it right.  Of course that's a bit of work and it depends on whether you are looking to fix it for the long term or just wanting to patch it back together for a short term fix.

[image: Photo of Damage]

Comment: Tear what whole thing out? The exterior wall, along with siding? No. Not necessary even for the long term. There's no real problem.

Comment: @isherwood  As I said, it's impossible to tell from the photo.  I would not, however, assume that it's all ok.  Perhaps you work that way but I would not.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood & FreeMan here, in that the damage to the rest of the subfloor and the bottom plate of the wall appears to be small.  It looks like the "damage" is mostly a discoloration of the surface of the wood.  Now if you were to poke at the bottom plate (the 2x) and it falls apart, then that's a different story.